# White space created when adding text on background image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a portfolio page and I'd like to have fixed images as the background. However, I'm running into a problem: whenever I try to add text on top, it messes up the alignment or something and creates unwanted white space. I don't know how to fix this issue. Any help?

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.fixed-bg1 {
  background-image: url("https://41.media.tumblr.com/34c944c6ee5cfad2f890373761673d17/tumblr_nx1ws7Ll2C1r2qfqzo1_1280.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.fixed-bg2 {
  background-image: url("https://41.media.tumblr.com/94b7a3f67a5bcd979867546e59442060/tumblr_nyqwdvxMkt1qglw5bo1_1280.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.fixed-bg3 {
  background-image: url("https://36.media.tumblr.com/0fe3ff92db9ba0668a8d45b69aedc274/tumblr_o25axx1VQc1r9s9v5o1_1280.png");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.fixed-bg4 {
  background-image: url("https://36.media.tumblr.com/433d66f1514d31e9e788959fa4eaedb5/tumblr_o2di9zXy7V1rexc04o1_1280.jpg");
  min-height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.text-margin {
  margin-top: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Luke</a>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#bg1">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bg2">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bg3">Portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#bg4">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>

<div id="bg1" class="fixed-bg1">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum la la la</h1>
</div>

<div id="bg2" class="fixed-bg2"></div>

<div id="bg3" class="fixed-bg3"></div>

<div id="bg4" class="fixed-bg4"></div>
```

Also ignore the actual images themselves, they're just placeholders for the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**fix margin** of `h1` it's **taking margin** `H1`  taking margin of your **bootsrap css** now you can overwrite `h1` margin

```
 margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
```

like this

```
.fixed-bg1 h1{margin:0;}
```

Comment: Yes it is currently set to margin:67em;

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I only just started learning web dev a few days ago.